# Set focus in input of ngbootstrap popover

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using an ng-bootstrap popover to do filtering on a table. Based on the type (int,string,date,..) of the data in the column i want to show different kinds of filtering options. This works as intended, but i also want the corresponding input field to be focused when the popover is displayed.

ng-boostrap popover exposes an output called (shown) that i've tried to use in order to call a function for focusing my input, this does not seem to work.

If I call the same function from ngAfterViewChecked() it focuses as intended, but since this function is called many times it doesn't seem to be a very good solution (on my own site it is called around 150 times per toggle of the popover). I'm not sure why it would be called so many times, but that's not the main point of the question.

I have created a plunker that shows my issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fr0nI1GiRT22UWXaNZwJ?p=preview

Html:

```
<div style="display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" placement="bottom"
        [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Popover on bottom" (shown)="selectInput()" container="body"  triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="p.toggle()">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
</div>

<ng-template #popContent>
  <div class="filter-popover">
    <div>
      <label for="filterbox">Filter: </label>
      <input id="filterbox" [(ngModel)]="appliedFilter" class="form-control form-control-sm" [focus]="focusSettingEventEmitter" />
    </div>
    <div class="popover__controls d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="p.close()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="p.close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnChanges, EventEmitter, HostListener, ViewChild, ViewChildren, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-popover-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/popover-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdPopoverBasic implements AfterViewChecked {
      public focusSettingEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    selectInput() {
        this.focusSettingEventEmitter.emit(true);
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
      //if i call it here it will focus it, but this function is run 150 times on my site (here around 3), so we dont want to do that
      //this.selectInput();
      //console.log("checked")
    }
}
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective {
    @Input('focus') focusEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;

    constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.focusEvent.subscribe((event:any) => {
            this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.element.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
        });
    }
}
```

From what I've read what other users say about focusing inputs is that you should do it in the function AfterViewInit, this is however not applicable to me since the component is initialized when the page loads, and i want the focus to happen once the popover is displayed/shown

Would love some help to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have made an attempt to use AfterViewChecked. It's true, it will be fired +150 times, but not if you set a condition:

```
start;

....    
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if(this.start){
     this.selectInput();
     console.log("checked");
     this.start = false;
  }
}
```

and set start tot true only when the popover toggling button is clicked:

```
  <button ...(click)="start = true; p.toggle()">
```

Now check it in the demo console, it's only fired when needed and the focus works.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BgPtaGk2SUmx9zTShJZj?p=preview)**

Comment: A good workaround, I also realized that the shown is emitted before the template was rendered.. if i set a timeout in the select input function it also works.

Comment: I tried to follow this but I am getting this error - cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

Please look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959569/not-able-to-navigate-ngbpopover-close-button-using-tab